# display only bmp images in android

Tags: android, image

I am querying the mediastore database by filtering only for bmp format images.The code is as follows..

```
 private static final String WHERE_CLAUSE = "(" + Media.MIME_TYPE + " in (?))";
private static final String[] ACCEPTABLE_IMAGE_TYPES = new String[] {
         "image/bmp"
};
Cursor c = activity.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                mPROJECTION, WHERE_CLAUSE, ACCEPTABLE_IMAGE_TYPES, MEDIA_COUNT + " DESC");
```

But I am unable to show them in grid view.
If anyone know the answer please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution by myself.And I am posting answer for my own question.
As **png**, **jpeg**, **gif** formats, I thought **bmp** is the extension of **bmp** image formats.But after checking the database file I came to know that  "**x-ms-bmp**" is the format for bmp images.So now my code is as follows

//These are the objects of where and where clause arguments

```
 private static final String WHERE_CLAUSE = "(" + Media.MIME_TYPE + " in (?))";
private static final String[] ACCEPTABLE_IMAGE_TYPES = new String[] {
     "image/x-ms-bmp"
};
```

//Here is my cursor

```
Cursor c = activity.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                mPROJECTION, WHERE_CLAUSE, ACCEPTABLE_IMAGE_TYPES, MEDIA_COUNT + " DESC");
```

Thats all.